# Getting the Mouse's X and Y coordinates with respect to an arbitrary Dom element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom, mouseevent

I'm looking for the most reliable way to retrieve the X and Y coordinates of the mouse in terms of some arbitrary DOM element, during the events `onmousemove`, `onmouseup`, and `onmousedown`.

When writing vanilla javascript I could use `e.layerX` and `e.layerY` to get a number that appears to be correct.  Though, in the Mozilla docs, they recommend [against using it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX).  Now moving to React, (in my specific Components render function)

`return <canvas onMouseMove={ e => this.handleMouseMoved(e) }></canvas>`.

I no longer have access to `layerX` or `layerY`.  I also cannot access `offsetX` which in the past I have used in conjunction with `clientX` or `clientY` to derive the element relative coordinates of the mouse.

There are so many different ways to read coordinates.  I'm confused about their meaning and when they should be used.  So if I want to see `x: 0, y: 0` when I mouse over the top-left corner, and `x: <DomElement.width>, y: <DomElement.height` when I mouse over the bottom-right corner, which event/synthetic-event should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

React uses SyntheticEvents and then "pools" those events to improve performance (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

To get the "native" event it must be saved from the synthetic event since React's SyntheticEvent "will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event callback has been invoked".

What does that mean?

```
<canvas onMouseMove={ e => { 
  let nativeEvent = e.nativeEvent;
  this.handleMouseMoved(nativeEvent); 
}></canvas>
```

The `nativeEvent` will have `offsetX/Y`, `layerX/Y` etc you are looking for.